# How can I sort a neural network layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am working on a multi-target regression problem in Keras and I would like the predicted values in the last layer to be sorted. I am currently implementing something like this:

```
# Lambda layer
import tensorflow as tf
def sort_layer(tensor):
    return tf.sort(tensor)        

# Training model on train set
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Lambda

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100,input_dim=X_train.shape[1],activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(150,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(50,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1],activation="linear"))
model.add(Lambda(sort_layer))
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")
model.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=100,batch_size=10, verbose=0)
```

This doesn't seem to be working every time as some predictions don't come out sorted. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong and suggest a good fix?

Thank you!